# How can I Align a Distribution of Coordinates to a Perfect Alignment?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, pca

I have a group of coordinates which are in the same direction for an example:

Coordinates for vertical projection: 8,15; 9,27; 10,40; 7,55; 5,68.

Coordinates for horizontal projection: 8,27; 20,28; 36,26; 51,25; 64,27;

How can I align the coordinates in vertical projection and horizontal projection so for all the vertical projection coordinates have a single X value for example: 8,15; 8,27; 8,40; 8,55; 8,68. and for the horizontal projection have the same Y value for example: 8,28; 20,28; 36,28; 51,28; 64,28?

[image: Braille]
I've already detected the coordinate for each dots in the image, but the coordinates are not perfectly align (see coordinates example above).

That's why, I really need any suggestion how can I align those detected dots into perfect alignment for each lines (as highlighted in colors).

I've ever heard of Principal Component Analysis, but I don't know where to start if I use PCA because there are hardly any good example for aligning coordinates.

If there are any other good recommendation, I really hope someone would like to share it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How do you want to align the coordinates? By average of the axis? Maybe you should use linear regression : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: is this possible with a lot of lines with a single run?
or will it just align the coordinates in just a single line?

Comment: Linear regression is used to find a linear function that best describes the "alignment" of the coordinates.  I'm not sure if that's what you need, that's for you to decide. Maybe you should better describe what you need in the question.

Comment: Dear @BagelzoneHa'bonè, please read my edited question, I really need any suggestion how to align those coordinates in a single run. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mhh, since you use OpenCV you may be interessted in this approach which is based on matrix manipulation on pixel scale:

1) Create a binary picture (black/white), therefore you initialize a black picture (or just a zero-matrix of desired size).

2) Since you already got your points unsorted (and therefore the matrix indices), you can do a for loop. So for every point you change the color of the pixel in the binary image to white. If you have to take care of memory you can use a sparse matrix.

3) To get the sorted list in x or in y you just walk trough the corresponding row/column of your binary image and return the column/row of every white pixel.

As a result you end up with a nice binary image and your sorted points.

**Edit**: Since you want to do some averaging in one component, this can be handelt by a boolean expression such that you set one coodinate within the desired range to the specific value. A second solution would be, that you rotate your input image before extracting the points. In OpenCV rotations are already implemented, you only have to find out the angle.

Cheers TL

Comment: Actually, I had already done a rotate (skew correction) before extracting the points, but I still get a not perfectly aligned coordinates of the dots.

Comment: Did you calibrate your camera via a findChessboardCorner and calibrateCamera? I did this, to compensate the errors caused by the lens. As a result if I undistort any other picture taken with the same camerasystem I end up with perfect lines. Due to the datapoints in your original post, I think that you are effected by a barrel distortion.